# Manually label images for machine learning

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, data-annotations, data-generation

[image]I need to manually label pixels as white or black in an image, to use to train machine learning algorithm.

I have some blobs on a uniform background. I want a tool such that, when I click on an individual blob, it can detect its boundaries from the background, and paint it white. The blobs have distinct boundaries, and are brighter than the background. Then, once I am done with all the blobs, I want to click on the background, and paint it black, i.e. everything that hasn't been labeled as a blob should turn black.

I am interested in free software that works in Ubuntu and/or Mas OS.

This is example input

Comment: Sharing an input image and a separate, correctly marked up output image would help.

Comment: If your blobs are clearly defined and lighter than the background, it should be easy to do automatically without needing to click, surely?

Comment: Do you have any concrete advice? Well they are not that clear, because if I try automatically with thresholding, it picks up other stuff, too. So I want to get some manually labeled images, do data augmentation and train a convolutional neural network. Also, how do I upload images here?

Comment: Click on 4th item to right after `Bold` and `Italic` in Formatting menu to add pictures.

Comment: I just uploaded example input. I don't have example output, but in the image above, you can imagine if the white-ish circular blobs were all white, and the background all black.

Comment: Are you envisaging something like Photoshop's magic wand tool with a variable size brush you can dab/paint blobs with and you can paint normally to mean *"yes, select this"* or with a control key pressed to mean *"please exclude this"*? GIMP has a magick wand and runs on macOS and Ubuntu...

Comment: The former. But rather than have to fully manually fill in the blob, just be able to click once on the blob, and complete it. What is the software called for this, what specific tool do I use, and how? Thanks

Comment: **Image**J may be another option.

Comment: How do I use the magic want, where do I see it in gimp? I am trying out gimp right now, but don't know the right option.